# What do you call the subtraction of a known model?

Tags: regression, terminology

Suppose you have observations of sample absorbance at given frequency and sample temperature. You know that the temperature effect is linear, i.e. absorbance = base_absorbance + temp_constant * temp.

Each sample has a different temperature, so you decide to fit a linear model predicting absorbance based on temp. Then you subtract these predictions from the original absorbances. Now you have the residuals of the temperature model and you call them normalised observations.

Now that you removed the effect of the temperature, you move on to predicting the octane number from the normalised observations. What would you call the normalisation step?

Could it be called detrending even though it is done using observed temperature rather than observed time?

Comment: Over-arching advice (perhaps vacuous) is to use terminology that people in your sub-field will understand because they use it routinely. That said, and working backwards (3) detrending has a strong default meaning of taking out a time (or in some fields: spatial) trend, which doesn't rule out broader uses, but you need to flag your use (2) "normalise" means so many different things, even in statistical sciences,  that my advice is to avoid the term (1) residual is a good statistical term with a long pedigree that fits what you're doing.

Comment: @nickcox suggestions are helpful. My view is that you need to explore your proposed model structure a bit more widely to understand the relationships rather than imposing a kind of a priori, deterministic, hierarchical or sequential functional form. In other words, why not use the same approach with octane number that was done with absorbance? Comparing the dependence of residuals between the two models should be informative. Next, you don't mention it but it defies common sense that the data doesn't have a time stamp. This would be potentially quite useful information.

Comment: I asked this question because I was trying to come up with a generic name for a software component (in a programming language with no standard statistical library) where the use isn't fixed to temperature or linear model. I'll name it Residuals per Nick Cox's suggestion. **Just one additional question: Would it be correct to say "Residuals with respect to temperature"?** Thank you. p.s. @nick-cox feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. I would always favour explicit detail such as "residual after subtracting linear dependence on temperature". (I am assuming that some modest science in your example makes linear dependence a very good approximation over some empirical range.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over-arching advice (perhaps vacuous) is to use terminology that people in your sub-field will understand because they use it routinely.

That said, and working backwards:

3. **detrending** has a strong default meaning of taking out a *time trend* (or in some fields a *spatial trend*). That doesn't rule out broader uses, but you need to flag your own use so that it is clearly decoded. The use of *trend* as a very general synonym for *pattern* or *relationship* is not outrageous, but my personal view is that it weakens a good word.

2. **normalise** means so many different things, even in statistical sciences, that my advice is to avoid the term. Other uses include various kinds of scaling or standardization and transformations to be closer to normal or Gaussian distribution.

1. **residual** is a good statistical term with a long pedigree, including John Herschel and J.S. Mill, that fits what you're doing.